# Maven - proxy in settings causes connection error to company nexus

Tags: java, maven, proxy

I am using the following `settings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <localRepository>C:\Dev\m2</localRepository>


    <proxies>
        <proxy>
          <id>1</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <username>user</username>
          <password>pass</password>
          <host>host</host>
          <port>port</port>
          <nonProxyHosts>127.0.0.1|localhost|maven</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>

        <proxy>
          <id>1</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>https</protocol>
          <username>user</username>
          <password>pass</password>
          <host>host</host>
          <port>port</port>
          <nonProxyHosts>127.0.0.1|localhost|maven</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>nexus1</id>
                    <url>http://company-nexus.com</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>nexus2</id>
                    <url>http://company-deploy-nexus.com</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>nexus1</id>
                    <url>http://company-nexus.com</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>

</settings>
```

which has proxy settings and the company nexus configured. I want the proxy settings because in one of the projects I the maven central repository configured

```
<repository>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
</repository>
```

however when a project that can retrieve everything from the company nexus (i.e. does not require access to `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2` through the proxy tries to download a dependency I get

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project someproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project groupId:artifactId:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to collect dependencies at junit:junit:jar:4.12: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.12: 
Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:4.12 from/to central (http://company-nexus.com): 
Access denied to: http://company-nexus.com/nexus/content/groups/public/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom, ReasonPhrase: URLBlocked. -> [Help 1]
```

When I remove the proxy settings in `settings.xml` I get a build-success.

Again, I need those proxy settings for some but not all projects as our company nexus has most of the repos

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your local nexus repository hostnames in nonProxyHosts tag

```
<nonProxyHosts>localhost|company-deploy-nexus.com|company-nexus.com|localhost</nonProxyHosts>
```